# What is this encrypted with or where can I find examples of encryptions to compare it with?

Tags: encryption, hash

I have a hash thingy I am trying to decode and I have done relatively little with encryption, though I would like to try to learn some more.

The hash is: `1YMTpavsFq7ykllC3CCsg3e1li31re1nROxuW1wqIqpk` and I have no clue what to look for. I already tried MD5 (it failed) and I am going to try AES256, SHA-256, and AES-CBC.

I believe it may have something to do with SSL, though I'm not sure.

**EDIT**: I believe this may affect the decryption of some data that followed:

`U2FsdGVkX18yMLwr6K3OxZrCLbKMDPi+9uQ8dYkgXNia/sQF/I1dNUX9NmWBCtcYVVpbdPABMZQOuCXzE8OVqKPQw/29sjPTZfrCKxSK11p5XWDWBAVn9DP3nAlscBlLhWfQvnFrsMSuhNouWTvX7Kl2jzjXrQZEwS739HAC6nHxbDL3QAJcJBHZXo4RWQ66KlsZnsKipqHvyCkWXTZJ4QZ+nofK93eDp/5KfDfagdze+pQ78VAOlvFaPM4MIG0ymi9olEmhGTXD7UV4oRBCiZE46tykTjjlYkllk0AcgRYtyGjbMN89CTQmQe2alN1fGXJM62v1TAjgabx3RiLjWuMxjHbpJXYF22iiQjSZ36Y=`

which makes me think it has more to do with SSL than with hashing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This *looks like* some [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding of a sequence of exactly 33 bytes. "33" is not a common length (it is not a power of two, and cryptographers are complete suckers for powers of two). The bytes don't appear to have some recognizable pattern.

You are doing it wrong. If you want to recognize the algorithm, you should be reverse-engineering the code which produced this value. You won't learn much by looking at the value alone (in fact, you would learn only what I stated in the first paragraph).

Comment: I would do this, but I don't have access to the code. It isn't SSL? I got it and I believe it affects this following set of encrypted data `U2FsdGVkX18yMLwr6K3OxZrCLbKMDPi+9uQ8dYkgXNia/sQF/I1dNUX9NmWBCtcYVVpbdPABMZQOuCXzE8OVqKPQw/29sjPTZfrCKxSK11p5XWDWBAVn9DP3nAlscBlLhWfQvnFrsMSuhNouWTvX7Kl2jzjXrQZEwS739HAC6nHxbDL3QAJcJBHZXo4RWQ66KlsZnsKipqHvyCkWXTZJ4QZ+nofK93eDp/5KfDfagdze+pQ78VAOlvFaPM4MIG0ymi9olEmhGTXD7UV4oRBCiZE46tykTjjlYkllk0AcgRYtyGjbMN89CTQmQe2alN1fGXJM62v1TAjgabx3RiLjWuMxjHbpJXYF22iiQjSZ36Y=` that looks like an SSL transmission, though I really know nothing of encryption.

Comment: Now _that_ one has some recognizable structure: once Base64-decoded, you can see that it begins with the ASCII encoding of "Salted__", which is a rather specific header that OpenSSL (the command-line tool) uses for its non-standard symmetric encryption format (that's unrelated to SSL, the protocol). Nothing specifies the actual encryption algorithm; it could be any one that OpenSSL supports.